# Ionic 4 : iOS Devices does not recognise the value 0 inside ngIf

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I'm using an if condition to check the count of an array and display if it has status 0.

This works perfectly in Android Devices but not working in iOS

```
<h3 *ngIf="status == 0">{{user.name}} </h3>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying?

Comment: edited please check

Comment: Try with `<h3 *ngIf="status === 0">{{user.name}} </h3>`

Comment: Have you checked what is the status returning? Maybe it's a string or something. Tried to change it to ` *ngIf="status === '0'" `

Comment: That was not the issue

Comment: in iOS the data type needs to be specified initially

Comment: @Bryyy got it right, you typed it as a string instead of a number

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Defined the status as a number and worked perfectly in both Android and iOS

```
status:number
```

Earlier it was

```
status:''
```

(which worked in Andoid, but not in iOS)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked what is the status returning?
Maybe it's a string or something. Try changing it to `<h3*ngIf="status === '0'">{{user.name}}</h3>`